# Get everything from table, but if network_id is 9, only take 2 of them

Tags: mysql

1st

```
SELECT
b.*,
network_9.*,
c.id AS click

FROM
`banners` AS b,
(
    SELECT id

    FROM `banners` AS b

    LEFT JOIN `clicks` AS c
    ON b.id = c.banner_id AND c.user_id = 1

    WHERE
        b.`network_id` = 9 AND
        b.`status` = 1 AND
        b.`type` IN(1, 2) AND
        c.`id` IS NULL

    LIMIT 2
) network_9

LEFT JOIN `clicks` AS c
ON b.id = c.banner_id AND c.user_id = 1

WHERE
    b.`network_id` NOT IN(network_0) AND
    b.`status` = 1 AND
    b.`type` IN(1, 2) AND
    c.`id` IS NULL

LIMIT 0, 10
```

2nd

```
SELECT
    b.*,
    c.id AS click

FROM
    `banners` AS b

LEFT JOIN `clicks` AS c
ON b.id = c.banner_id AND c.user_id = 1

WHERE
    b.`status` = 1 AND
    b.`type` IN(1, 2) AND
    c.id IS NULL

LIMIT 0, 10
```

I'm trying to get all rows from banners, but if network_id is 9, i would like to only take 2 of them, and then still all others.

The 1st attempt was somethin i tried, but failed.

And the 2nd is just the basic SQL, that takes all the rows, but doesn't check on the network_id

Comment: "if network_id is 9, i would like to only take 2 of them" The First two? The last two one ...

Answer (score 0):

My first and realy simple aproche is:

1. Select all rows from **banner** with network_id not equal 9 Select
2. Select all rows from **banner** with network_id equal 9 and limit them to 2

Second aproche would be:
Something like your first try:
Subselect all ids of rows from **banner** with network_id equal 9 and limit them 2. Main Select all rows but only allow rows dont having network_id equal 9 or inside the subselect

```
SELECT * FROM banner WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM banner WHERE network_id = 9 LIMIT 2) OR network_id != 9
```

Comment: I can't use this because of my MariaDB version. So can you make another one that does the same, but without the SELECET in the IN state ? :)

Comment: I never used MariaDB, so i have searched the net and found this: [https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/row_number/](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/row_number/)

**And this is my next try:**

`SELECT * FROM banner WHERE (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY network_id) < 3 AND network_id = 9 ) OR network_id != 9`